# How to change docker image built with spring-boot-maven-plugin env from POSIX to C.UTF-8 out of box

Tags: spring-boot

When I build image and check `locale` from container

```java
mvn spring-boot:build-image
docker run myimage
docker exec -it <id> locale
```

I got

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

My app fails on non ASCII string

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: ...
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.resolve(Unknown Source)
```

UTF-8 charset fixes error

```
docker run -e LANG=C.UTF-8 myimage
```

I want to add LANG env default value to image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <env>
                <BPE_LANG>C.UTF-8</BPE_LANG>
            </env>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

fixes the problem despite of `docker exec -it <id> locale` shows `POSIX`.

This is [scottfrederick](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30502) advice. I can’t thank you enough!